# Fail to initialize a property with default value of @Value annotation in Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin

I have a property that holds Redis port in my Redis config class.

```kotlin
@Value("\${redis.port:63799}")
lateinit var port: Integer

init {
        this.redisServer = RedisServer(port.toInt())
    }
```

When I run my code I get this error:

```
kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property port has not been initialized
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@Value` annotation is processed after the object is constructed.

The `init` block is part of object construction (it's common for all your constructors).

In other words, you're trying to reference the `@Value` injected property too early.

One way to work around it is to delay RedisServer construction in some way, i.e.:

1. Use lazyinit for the RedisServer.
2. Use `@PostConstruct` on a method to initialise the RedisServer.